# WPF: format background of button as grid layout

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

for my WPF-based application I want to have a button layout with an image based, 7px thick border, that can scale to any size.

My basic thought on how to achieve this (before getting into the needed xaml) was to slice the button background into 9 pieces:

[image: sliced layout]

- 4 corner slices (will never be stretched)
- 4 border slices (will be stretched either horizontal or vertical)
- 1 background slice (will be stretched both horizontal and vertical)

My first attempt to do this was to but a grid inside the Background-property of the button, but this seems not to work:

```
<Style x:Key="LoginButton" TargetType="Button">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="7"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="7"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonCornerLeftTop.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonCornerLeftBottom.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonCornerRightTop.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonCornerRightBottom.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonBorderLeft.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonBorderTop.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonBorderRight.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonBorderBottom.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonBackground.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            </Grid>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    ...
</Style>
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Template Property instead of Background. Try this

```
        <Style x:Key="LoginButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="7"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="7"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="7"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="7"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonCornerLeftTop.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonCornerLeftBottom.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonCornerRightTop.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonCornerRightBottom.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonBorderLeft.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonBorderTop.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonBorderRight.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonBorderBottom.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Source="/ron.launcher;component/Resources/button/buttonBackground.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: thanks, that works fine :)
but is there any way to change the background on MouseOver now?
Before I achieved it by changing the Background property in the IsMouseOver Trigger.

Comment: ControlTemplate do have Triggers facility . look for ControlTemplate.Triggers that can be set inside ControlTemplate

Comment: yes, that's how I did it before. But inside the Trigger I can only change the Button's properties, not the Grid I put directly in the ControlTemplate.